# Remove multiple images on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a [UberGallery](http://www.ubergallery.net) gallery page. For the sake of example, let's say it looks like [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8dmz4oh/)

My actual code has relative paths like:

```
   <li><a class="20141203" href="images/20141203/Camera2-2014120311584501.jpg" title="Dec 3 2014, 11:58:46" rel="20141203"><img src="resources/cache/125-8d30d775150af31eaeeed742c7d9105f.jpg" alt="Camera2-2014120311584501"/></a></li>
   <li><a class="20141203" href="images/20141203/Camera2-2014120311584502.jpg" title="Dec 3 2014, 11:58:47" rel="20141203"><img src="resources/cache/125-f378631630701cf7cb25b111f5c2ca11.jpg" alt="Camera2-2014120311584502"/></a></li>
```

I am trying to make it so if I right click multiple images, I will have the option to delete the images from my server. The image path I would like to remove is stored in `$image['file_path']` but I am unsure of how to use jQuery to use the right-click to select multiple images and remove the image.

I will probably have to use PHP or Ajax as well since Javascript cannot delete images from my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a piece of javascript catching the right-click on any `<img/>` element and sending an AJAX request. The script `your_delete_script.php` then has to read the posted filename and delete it on the server.

```
$(function() {    
      $('img').mouseup(function(e){ 
        if( e.button == 2 ) { 
          $.post('your_delete_script.php', {filename: $(this).attr('src')}, function() {});
      }); 
});
```

If there are any other `<img/>` elements, you have to assign a special class to those you wish to be deletable and assign the handler to that class.

Note that it might be unsafe to delete the file without checking whether the file is really an image which you wish to be deleted. Furthermore, it's not recommended to intrude into the user's browser handling by catching the right click which should open the context menu by default. Maybe you'll prefer a delete button or a double click event, depending on whether your site will be publicly available.